# Are there any modules to read shell scripts?

Tags: python, bash, shell, export, environment-variables

I'm making a python script right now, and I need to use some environment variables which are set in a bash shell script.

The bash script is something like:

```
#! /bin/sh

#sets some names:
export DISTRO="unified"
#export DISTRO="other"

#number of parallel builds
export BB_NUM_THREADS=2

#set build dir
export BUILDDIR=$PWD
```

Normally, I would just source this script in bash, then go do my builds. I'm trying to wrap python around the whole process to do some management of the output so I want to remove the manual `source ./this_script.sh` step.

What I want to do is read this script from python and then use `os.environ` to set up the variables within it. (I know this will not affect the parent, but only the current running Python instance and that's fine)

So to make my work easier, I'm trying to find out are there any modules which can "parse" the bash script and make use of the environment variables found within? Currently I'm doing this by hand and it's a bit of a pain.

If no such module exists to do *exactly* what I want, is there a more pythonic (read: easier/shorter) way of manually parsing a file in general, right now I'm doing this:

```
def parse_bash_script(fn):
  with open(fn) as f:
    for line in f:
      if not line[:1] == '#':   #ignore comments
        if "export" in line:
          line = line.replace(" ","").strip()
          var = line[6:line.find("=")]
          val = line[line.find("=")+1:len(line)]
          if "\"" in val:
            val = val[1:-1]
          os.environ[var]=val
```

Comment: Is the script really just comments and `export var=value` lines, or could there be other stuff in there?

Comment: In particular, after reading this more carefully… do you need `BUILDDIR=$PWD` to be evaluated the way the shell would? In other words, should `BUILDDIR` end up as something like `/Users/Mike/src/testing`, or as literal `$PWD`?

Comment: @abarnert - There is other stuff in there, as you noted. I was just going to update my `parse_bash_script()` method for the "special cases" such as `BUILDDIR=$PWD`... before I went down that route I wanted to see if I was missing some better option

Comment: OK, so the next question is: Is it safe to just execute the sh script? If so, that's probably the easiest answer. Handling variable sh-style substitution (especially if you have to deal with the fact that it's different depending on whether the shebang line specifies sh or bash) properly is even harder than handling quoting properly. And if you want to be fully general, what are you going to do with something like `foo=$(ls)`?

Comment: @abarnert - Yes, it would be safe to just execute that script, and it would be my preferred approach... seemed to me that it was not possible. I tried `source`ing it and a few other options using `Popen` but I can't seem to make that work. Did I miss something simple to get this script "sourced" within my Python environment?

Comment: Python can't `source` shell scripts because it's not the same language as `sh` or `bash`—but it's pretty easy to do with `Popen` to the actual shell, as I show in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

There is no module to do exactly what you want, but [`shlex`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/shlex.html#module-shlex) will do a lot of what you want. In particular, it will get the [quoting](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/shlex.html#parsing-rules), etc. right without you having to worry about it (which is the hardest part of this), as well as skipping comments, etc. The only thing it won't do is handle the `export` keywords.

The easy way around that is to preprocess:

```
with open(fn) as f:
    processed = f.read().replace('export ', '')
for line in shlex.split(processed):
    var, _, value = line.partition('=')
    os.environ[var] = val
```

---

It's a bit hackier, but you can also do it a bit less verbosely by post-processing. In particular, `shlex` will treat `export foo="bar spam eggs"` as two values: `export` and `foo="bar spam eggs"`, and you can just skip the ones that `== 'export'`, or where the partition finds nothing, or… For example:

```
with open(fn) as f:
    for line in shlex.split(f.read()):
        var, eq, value = line.partition('=')
        if eq:
            os.environ[var] = val
```

---

If you want to get fancier, you can construct a `shlex` object and (a) drive the parser directly from the file, and (b) control the parsing at a finer-grained level. However, I don't think that's necessary here.

---

Meanwhile, if you want to handle environment substitution (as the `BUILDDIR=$PWD` implies), this won't magically take care of that for you. You can make `configparser` do that for you with its [`ExtendedInterpolation` feature](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ExtendedInterpolation), but then you'll need to trick `configparser` into handling `shlex` syntax, at which point… why bother.

You can of course do it manually by writing your own interpolator, but that's hard to get right. You need to know the shell's rules for why `$PWD-foo` is the same as `${PWD}-foo`, but `$PWD_foo` is the same as `${PWD_foo}`, etc.

A better solution at this point—assuming the script is actually safe to run—would be to actually use a shell to do it for you. For example:

```
with open('script.sh') as f:
    script = f.read()
script += b'\nenv'
with subprocess.Popen(['sh'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as p:
    result = p.communicate(script)
for line in result.splitlines():
    var, _, value = line.partition('=')
    os.environ[var] = value
```

Of course this will also override things like `_=/usr/bin/env`, but probably not anything you care about.

Comment: Ideally I would like to have the shell run things, but when I execute the `with ...` and `result = p.comm...` lines I get back `"Traceback (most recent call last): File '<stdin>', line 1, in <module>  Attribute Error: __exit__"`. Seems to me subprocess didn't like running the shell scripts

Comment: Also, isn't `subprocess.Popen(['sh'], ` just opening a new shell inside of my Python session which is itself inside a shell? I wouldn't think variables that were sourced in the `'sh'` shell would be "set" in my python session

Comment: @Mike: That doesn't mean subprocess didn't like running the shell scripts; it means Python didn't like `Popen` as a context manager (aka "thingy in a with statement"). What version of Python are you using? As [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) say, context manager support was added in Python 3.2. In older versions, you have to do `p = subprocess.Popen(…)`, and then later make sure to close everything properly. But otherwise, it's the same.

Comment: @Mike: And yes, `Popen(['sh'])` will open a new shell as a subprocess of the Python interpreter. That will not automatically affect the variables in your Python interpreter (or any of its child processes). Which is why I add the `env` to the end of the script, and read and parse the output of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
def parse_bash_script(fn):
  with open(fn) as f:
    for line in f:
      if not line.startswith('#'):   #ignore comments
        if "export" in line:
          var, _, val = line.partition('=')
          var = var.lstrip()
          val = val.rstrip()
          if val.startswith('"'):
            vals = val.rpartition('"')
            val = vals[0][1]+vals[2]
          os.environ[var]=val
```

Comment: This won't necessarily handle quoting properly, which the OP's code explicitly does (although only partially successfully), so presumably he needs it. For example, the shell will handle doubled quotes in the middle of a string.

Comment: First, this still doesn't actually handle quoting properly—although at least it does it exactly the same as the OP's original code, instead of introducing different bugs. Second, you shouldn't have the `strip` calls there. _Maybe_ `var.lstrip()` and `val.rstrip()`, but not `strip`; `foo = bar` is _not_ an assignment in sh.

Comment: While I agree with your critique on `strip`, I don't see how preserving the spaces (on either side of the `=`) would help. Would `os.environ` really respect those spaces?

Comment: Yes, `os.environ` will respect the spaces; `os.environ['foo '] = ' bar'` will not overwrite `os.environ['foo']`, and if you later `subprocess` out to something else, it will only inherit the nearly-unusable variables `'foo '` instead of the easily-accidentally-usable `'foo'`.

Comment: I get that part. But what I was inquiring about was whether `os.environ` treats spaces around `=` in the same way as the shell does

Comment: `os.environ` doesn't understand `=`. It's just a dict. It treats spaces in the values and variables as literal spaces.

Comment: That's what I originally thought, which is why I stripped the spaces around the `=`. Doesn't `os.environ` then not only lose the meaning of `var = val`, but also make `var` (which would otherwise be usable in shell) unusable (as it would now be `var `)?

Comment: Again, `var = val` is _not a variable assignment in `sh`_. `var` would _not_ be usable in the shell, so it shouldn't be usable in Python. (What that line means is to run the program named by `var`, with `=` and `val` as its two arguments. This is part of the reason you can do `foo=bar spam=eggs baz` in the shell, which is very useful for build scripts.) So, turning that into `var=val` is a bad idea. Leaving in the spaces is hacky, but at least better, because the variable `'var '` will be nearly impossible to access from a subshell or other subprocess, so it's harmless.

Comment: That is a very awesome explanation. Thank you for sharing :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and based on the advice from abarnert, I decided to implement the solution as a subprocess call to a restricted bash shell, combined with shlex.

```
import shlex
import subprocess

filename = '/path/to/file.conf'
o, e = subprocess.Popen(
    ['/bin/bash', '--restricted', '--noprofile', '--init-file', 
     filename, '-i', '-c', 'declare'],
    env={'PATH': ''},
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()

if e:
    raise StandardError('conf error in {}: {}'.format(filename, e))

for token in shlex.split(o):
    parts = token.split('=', 1)
    if len(parts) == 2:
        os.environ[parts[0]] = parts[1]
```

The advantage to the restricted shell is that it blocks many of the undesirable or malicious side effects that may otherwise happen when executing a shell script. From the bash documentation:

> A restricted shell is used to set up an environment more controlled than the standard shell.  It behaves identically to bash with the exception that the following are disallowed or not performed:
>
> - changing directories with cd
> - setting or unsetting the values of SHELL, PATH, ENV, or BASH_ENV
> - specifying command names containing /
> - specifying a file name containing a / as an argument to the .  builtin command
> - Specifying a filename containing a slash as an argument to the -p option to the hash builtin command
> - importing function definitions from the shell environment at startup
> - parsing the value of SHELLOPTS from the shell environment at startup
> - redirecting output using the >, >|, <>, >&, &>, and >> redirection operators
> - using the exec builtin command to replace the shell with another command
> - adding or deleting builtin commands with the -f and -d options to the enable builtin command
> - Using the enable builtin command to enable disabled shell builtins
> - specifying the -p option to the command builtin command
> - turning off restricted mode with set +r or set +o restricted.